# compilation for multiple MIPS platforms

Tags: mips, cross-compiling, embedded-linux, toolchain, crosstool-ng

I have multiple MIPS platforms with different CPUs and different kernel and uclibc versions

I'm want to compile 'Hello World' program with **single** toolchain that will run on all of the devices.

I'm building the toolchain using crosstool-ng with the following configuration:

- MIPS1 arch type (-march=mips1)
- soft FPU (should work on devices w/wo hardware FPU)
- static executable (to avoid libraries dependencies failures)
- old kernel version (should be supported by devices with newer kernel)

Am I missing something?
I still have devices that the program is working only when using their dedicated toolchain (RTL819xD for example)

Thanks

Comment: In general it's close to "not possible". You can find, nevertheless, the most generic combination of flags to the compiler to produce some code which would be run on the subset of the devices. Most suitable architectures for this are not MIPS, rather x86, or ARM (to some extend)

Comment: I'm focusing on MIPS.
"the most generic combination of flags to the compiler" - that's exactly what I'm looking for